# Selenium Java Webdriver Selecting Historical Tab

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a public site.
http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/

Having trouble with the most basic thing.
Tried to select Historical tab that is on the page using the code below:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(false);


    // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");



    driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement tabHistorical;
        tabHistorical = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("k-item.k-state-default.k-last.k-tab-on-top.k-state-active"));
        tabHistorical.click();
```

Exception says no such element.
I don't see why.
Please go to site and press F12.  Element is there.

Comment: `k-item` is an element name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first go onto the page, the Historical tab is not selected, and so doesn't have the `k-tab-on-top` or `k-state-active` classes, it only obtains these when it is clicked and made the active tab.

Would it not be better in this instance to find the element by xpath? e.g.

```
WebElement tabHistorical = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rainTab\"]/ul/li[2]/span[2]"));
```

Comment: It does work.  I learned Java but the Html looks so Chinese to me.  Can you break down the xpath(".....") for me?    the answer will be accepted regardless of whether you break it down for me or not, but thought I would ask incase you are able to.

Comment: I can explain that I got the xpath by right-clicking the element in dev tools in Chrome and selecting Copy > Copy XPath

Comment: yeah.  that's pretty good info. for newbie like me.  I was trying to understand all that stuff and getting dizzy!  thx!